# Importing pg in react-native code

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, react-native, node-postgres

Being new to `react-native`, I am trying connect `postgreSQL` from my `react-native` application. I have installed `pg` module using this `npm install pg --save` command on my `react-native` application. However, if I try to import `pg` on my `App.js` (root component or any class component), I am getting the below error:

> **Import syntax(s): (Just tried different syntax)**
>
> - `import { Pool, Client } from 'pg';`
> - `import pg from 'pg';`
> - `import * as pg from 'pg';`
>
> **Error:**
>
> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `util` from `<REACT_APP_PATH>/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map
>
> **Note:** `const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');` syntax is working fine in `node + express` application.

**Question:**
Which is a very good solution in the following and why?

1. Use `pg` as `npm` module and import in `react-naive` application and connect to the postgreSQL and access tables?

1. How the `pg` module will be imported on `ios` or `android` build\package?
2. Does the `android/ios` have any native\node lib\module to connect `pg` that can be accessed by `react-native`?

Use a **node+express** API service and connect it from **react-native** app with the help of `fetch (axios like module)`?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you found a solution to this ? The second method is working fine but it require a second server to fetch.